# Scala 3 Enum - Manually define associated integers

Tags: scala, enums, scala-3

As of Scala 3.3.1 is there any way to set custom integer values for each case?

If I try with:

```
enum MyEnum:
  case E1
    override def ordinal: Int = 1
```

I get a this error:

`the ordinal method of enum class MyEnum can not be defined by the user`

Comment: What's your expected usage? I would tend to never rely on the ordinal of an enum, too easy to change it by mistake. I would define an explicit number attribute instead.

Comment: Considering that this value could be used in various places generated by compiler - for instance `Mirror.Sum` - if you want to use a different ordinals implement them as parallel to the compiler's ones. (And if you want to create a finite set of `Int` values there are better ways than overriding `ordinal`).